# What takes priority of urls out of Django and AngularJS?

Tags: django, angularjs, django-urls

I am using Django with Angular... When I refresh my pages, I would prefer Angular to handle routing. So I need to render layout.html (via django), and after that let Angular manage the urls and routing to the correct controller.

For example in Django:

`urls.py:`

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
  url(r'^api/', include(v1_api.urls)),
  url(r'^.*$', 'home.views.index'),
)
```

`views.py`

```
def index(request):
  return render(request, 'layout.html', {})
```

But the priority of Django is not according to the number of lines written. Because now after refreshing, the urls that start with `api`, render `index` as well. It means Django didn't understand that the urls that start by api have higher priority.

So, whats priority of urls in Django, and has using Angular changed this?

Comment: can you give me a sample url from v1_api.urls. most probably you are not ending v1_api.urls url with '$' or you might be hiting wrong url as in your case when you hit a wrong url it will render 'home.views.index' to verify that remove url(r'^.*$', 'home.views.index'), for a while and check

Comment: i used TastyPie Module in Django and the sample url is : "/api/v1/news/3/?format=json" .... it works correctly and show json data at first time ... but when i "manually" refresh the page, i redirect to index... because the Django didn't understand that the url that start by api has higher priority... So, Django render index again. (i updated my  Question for better understanding... plz read again)

Comment: try that again by removing `url(r'^.*$', 'home.views.index')` i suppose when you are reloading the page something is causing to change the url(check you request log) in fact what you can do is render `'home.views.index'` at error 500. This is definitely not an issue because of angular.

Comment: Django will _always_ return the first matching pattern. If an url that should match an api call is returning the index page, something else is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django will always return the first matching pattern.

i found the solution:

in url.py i changed reg-exp, instead of

```
url(r'^.*$', 'home.views.index'),
```

i used :

```
url(r'^.*/$', 'home.views.index'),
```

now if Django didn't find any matches, shows index.

Comment: Important: order matters, your catch-all "index" url should be the last in order to make this work.

Comment: Django is likely serving the webpage (at least in development). Django will go first. If it can't find a route it should 'fall-through', as your answer states.